# Asus M2N SLI Deluxe motherboard dead?

Tags: motherboard

I have this 4-5 year old mainboard Asus M2N SLI Deluxe.
Yesterday, I plugged in a usb stick at the front side of the computer casing, apparently in a defect port. The system froze, and now it won't boot, without beeps.

I've stripped all parts out of the pc (graphics card, RAM, hard disks, etc), except for the cpu and its fan.

When I turn the system on, the motherboard led lights up, the cpu fan spins, but nothing happens.

Is my motherboard dead, or is something else the problem (Is the board supposed to give no beeps

Comment: You would need to put the RAM back in also. I would also keep the video card in to see what is going on on boot.

Comment: I've tried putting in RAM four times: two different brands in two different slots (apart from eachother), still no beeps. Regarding the video card, I'm expecting beeps when the mainboard detects errors, eg the video card is missing. It is not giving those.

Comment: Sounds very much like your MB is dead. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah I was afraid of that. But wanted to be sure, would be embarassing if it's not broken and I find out after getting rid of parts ^^ Thanks anyway.

Comment: In my experience the M2N SLI Deluxe is a very flakey board, prone to sudden failure. A couple of months ago I was working through a batch of 4 in-house machines sent back to IT Support as 'suspect' - all machines had an M2N SLI Deluxe motherboard - we scrapped 2 as faulty, killed one trying to reflash it and 'fixed' the last by swapping out the BIOS with one of the scrapped motherboards.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem since yesterday with my ASUS M32N-SLI Deluxe. I think it is 9-10 years old. I don't have another CPU to test it. If I remove all components with the exception of the CPU the internal speaker of the MB beeps three times (means: no memory installed). If I add one of my four RAM-DIMMS in one of the four RAM-Slots of the MB, no beep occurs at all. @OP: Did you try starting your MB **without RAM** back then? I highly doubt that all of my four RAM-DIMMS are broken/fried (sadly I can't verify that too).